# Where is the actual character set for Ada program text defined?

Tags: ada, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to make a [tree-sitter](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/) parser, so that IDEs (in this case, Vim) can parse and do more advanced manipulation of Ada program text, such as extract-subprogram and rename-variable. But there seem to be some problems defining the character set.

In the [Ada 2012 Reference Manual](http://ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-2-1.html), I found a list of vague category descriptions, of the form 'Any character whose General Category is X' which means that for instance, besides the underscore, [all of these](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pc/list.htm) ( ‿ ⁀ ⁔ ︳ ︴ ﹍ ﹎ ﹏ ＿) are also allowed in an identifier, which seems absurd, and GNAT rejects with 'illegal character'. The list is prefaced by this statement:

"The actual set of graphic symbols used by an implementation for the visual representation of the text of an Ada program is not specified."

Does that really mean there's no way to know which characters should be accepted?

[Two pages on](http://ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-2-3.html), these examples are explicitly given as valid identifiers, and yet GNAT 2021 rejects them:

```
procedure Main is
   Πλάτων  : constant := 12;     -- Plato
   Чайковский : constant := 12;  -- Tchaikovsky
   θ, φ : constant := 12;        -- Angles
begin
   null;
end Main;
```

```
$ gprbuild
using project file foo.gpr
Compile
   [Ada]          main.adb
main.adb:2:04: error: declaration expected
main.adb:2:05: error: illegal character
main.adb:3:04: error: declaration expected
main.adb:3:05: error: illegal character
main.adb:4:05: error: illegal character
gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
```

Where is the actual character set for Ada programs defined? Has GNAT 2021 got it wrong?

An example program using Unicode characters in identifiers is below for your experimentation. Note that the use of wide characters in the literal string is outside the scope of the question.

main.adb:

```
with Ada.Wide_Text_IO; use Ada.Wide_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   δεδομένα_πράμα : constant Wide_String := "Ο Πλάτων θα ενέκρινε";
begin
   Put_Line (Δεδομένα_πράμα);
end Main;
```

foo.gpr

```
project foo is

   for Source_Dirs use (".");
   for Main use ("main.adb");

   package Compiler is
      for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-gnatW8", "-gnatiw");
   end Compiler;

end foo;
```

To build & run:

```
gprbuild
./main
```

Comment: GNAT must be told to use UTF-8... `-gnatW8` I believe

Comment: Thank you Egil, that's correct. Now I see that even some of those weird squiggles I called 'absurd' are valid in identifiers (but not at the end, and no two consequtive ones), but not all!

Comment: I hope nobody thinks I would recommend naming variables δεδομένα‿πράμα. It's a bad idea, I just want the parser to be able to accept all valid Ada programs.

Comment: I’d strongly recommend not using international characters in library unit names (at any rate, on case-insensitive [but preserving] systems such as Windows, macOS). [PR81114](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81114)

Answer (score 5):

All Ada versions since Ada 2005 have required that implementations support UTF-8 source code, however for Ada 83 & 95 compatibility don't require it to be the *default* encoding.  GNAT's default source encoding is [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), although it helpfully switches to UTF-8 if a [byte-order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is found.  To explicitly specify file encoding, you can pass the `-gnatW8` flag, [or one of a number of other options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gnat_ugn_unw/Character-Set-Control.html).

However, while that allows UTF-8 in source files, identifiers are still limited to Latin-1 in GNAT, you must also pass the `-gnatiw` flag to allow wide characters in identifiers.  It seems that GNAT does not default to it because you can craft very bizarre identifiers (as you noted), but also because identifiers would no longer be properly case-insensitive; GNAT does minimal case folding on any wide character set, [other than characters present in other encodings it supports](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/ada/csets.adb;h=5feb3eeb309f8618ac6ae302921e3cee66cc2566;hb=HEAD).

[ARM § 2.3](http://ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-2-3.html) specify the requirements for an identifier:
`identifier ::= identifier_start {identifier_start | identifier_extend}`,
where `identifier_start` can be summarized as anything in Unicode general category L, and the remaining characters can be numbers, `punctuation_connector`s, decimal marks, and non-whitespace combining marks—with the additional restriction of “An identifier shall not contain two consecutive characters in category `punctuation_connector`, or end with a character in that category. ”

Going beyond your question, note that despite all these flags, strings are *still* encoded as Latin-1 (conflictingly, string literals are UTF-8, just not the underlying string :/).  You'll need to use [`Ada.Strings.UTF_Encoding`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-4-11.html), `Wide_Wide_String`s, and/or a library such as [VSS](https://github.com/AdaCore/VSS) for Unicode string handling.

Comment: okay, but even with gnatW8 and gnatiw, identifiers containing '﹏' are still invalid according to GNAT. So the question still stands; how do I know which are and which aren't valid, and has GNAT got it right according to the standard, or is the standard too vague to be able to tell?

Comment: it also does not appear to hold, that -gnatiw disables case folding. I can still use 'δεδομένα_πράμα' and 'Δεδομένα_πράμα' as equivalent.

Comment: Correction: GNAT doesn't do Unicode case folding, it only does case folding for a subset of characters that are also present in the other non-wide character sets it supports.

Comment: And per [ARM § 2.3](http://ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-2-3.html): “An identifier shall not contain two consecutive characters in category punctuation_connector, or end with a character in that category.”, and it also may not start with anything but a letter.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts, the links, and compiler flags, and hence I've given my upvote. But unfortunately this still doesn't answer the question. You would only need to provide the definition for one of the character classes mentioned (e.g. `identifier_start`) as long as I get the full list of characters, and how you arrived at that conclusion, either from the standard or GNAT's point of view (if different). So far I see no reason why ﹏ is not okay but ‿ is. They are both in [Unicode's 'Punctuation, Connector' category](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pc/list.htm).

Comment: Looking at the compiler source [starting here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ada/scng.adb#L2485), the problem might be if WAVY LOW LINE can’t be in NFKC (AI12-0004), but otherwise it should be acceptable. Might be  compiler bug, ofc

Comment: The problem _is_ that WAVY LOW LINE is not in NFKC, see [this amazing document](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/DerivedNormalizationProps.txt), search for FE4F. OMG